# Typescript - Conditionally create duplicate elements

Tags: html, angular, typescript, duplicates, element

I have a variable which users of my application can modify, say:

```
let myValue = 3;
```

In my html I wish to create as many duplicates of an element as the value of the variable is.

In my case, `myValue is 3`, then we create the div element 3 times.

```
<div>I am a duplicate.</div>
<div>I am a duplicate.</div>
<div>I am a duplicate.</div>
```

`myValue` can be a higher or lower number as well. Whatever it is, I would like to have that many duplicates of my element. How can I achieve this?

P.S. I am still new to Angular and Typescript so please don't go hard on me if this is a rather simple question.

Comment: You can use `ngFor` and iterate over an array whose length is based on `myValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// creates an array in TS file based on myValue
duplicates = Array(myValue).fill(null).map( (x,index) => index );


// use ngFor in HTML 
<div ngFor="let duplicate of duplicates">
  <div>I am a duplicate. {{ duplicate }}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the Iterator Protocol.

**HTML**

```
<ol>
  <li *ngFor="let i of value">{{ i }}</li>
</ol>
```

**TypeScript**

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  _value = 3;
  get value(){
    let iterable = {
      length: this._value,
      index: 0,
      next: () => {
        if (iterable.index < iterable.length) {
         return {value: iterable.index++, done: false};
       } else {
         iterable.index = 0;
         return {done: true};
       }
     },
      [Symbol.iterator]: function() { return this }
    };
    return iterable;
  }
}
```